# How do i fix? IDX21323: RequireNonce is 'System.Boolean'. OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.Nonce was null

Tags: c#, okta, okta-signin-widget

I am getting this issue.

IDX21323: RequireNonce is 'System.Boolean'. OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.Nonce was null, OpenIdConnectProtocol.ValidatedIdToken.Payload.Nonce was not null. The nonce cannot be validated. If you don't need to check the nonce, set OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator.RequireNonce to 'false'. Note if a 'nonce' is found it will be evaluated.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Below is my code:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
           
            ConfigureAuth(app);
           
            

        }
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
           

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = _clientId,
                ClientSecret = _clientSecret,
                
                Authority = _authority,
                RedirectUri = _redirectUri,
                ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken,
                Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters { NameClaimType = "name" },
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                     

                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = async n =>
                    {
                        //  Exchange code for access and ID tokens

                        var tokenClient = new TokenClient($"{_authority}/v1/token", _clientId, _clientSecret);

                        var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestAuthorizationCodeAsync(n.Code, _redirectUri);
                        if (tokenResponse.IsError)
                        {
                            throw new Exception(tokenResponse.Error);
                        }

                        var userInfoClient = new UserInfoClient($"{_authority}/v1/userinfo");
                        var userInfoResponse = await userInfoClient.GetAsync(tokenResponse.AccessToken);

                        var claims = new List<Claim>(userInfoResponse.Claims)
                         {
                                new Claim("id_token", tokenResponse.IdentityToken),
                                new Claim("access_token", tokenResponse.AccessToken)
                          };

                        n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaims(claims);
                    },
                    

                },
            });

        }
```

I tried the chrome fix that had been suggested in article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/samesite/owin-samesite but it did not work and have been trying for 6 days now without knowing how to fix this. I am not using Azure. I am trying this on my local system with visual studio